# How to extract Map from collection of objects, with the key as one of the objects same field and value the actual objects

Tags: functional-programming, kotlin

I have a structure like this:

```
data class LocationRSSIEvent(
    val idRSSIEvent: Long = 0,
    val identifier: Identifier,
    val rssi: Int,
    val timestampRSSIEvent: Long) : LocationEvent()
```

I want to be able to use some function in Kotlin to get result like this:

```
fun getRSSIMultimap(rssiEvents: Collection<LocationRSSIEvent>): Map<Identifier, List<LocationRSSIEvent>>
```

So for example i have a list of LocationRSSIEvents, but each LocationRSSIEvent inside of it can contain different Identifier object. I want to be able to extract LocationRSSIEvents that have the same Identifier to the Map that will contain Identifier as a key of this map, and the list of those LocationRSSIEvents that have the same Identifier as a value.

I hope everything is clear, is there a simple way to achive this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you're just looking for the [`groupBy`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/group-by.html) method from the standard library:

```
rssiEvents.groupBy { it.identifier }
```